# How can I concatenate strings, only if value does not already exist

Tags: excel, string-concatenation

I have a csv database with loads of colours, what I want is to concatenate all unique colours and separate them by a comma. I need to somehow only include string values once. See example below...

COLOUR
red
red
green
blue
red
blue
green
silver

I would need this to output as - 
red,green,blue,silver

Comment: Can you give us more explanation what you trying to achieve exactly? If you need to do this process once, you can use the "Remove duplicates" built in excel functionality. If its not the case, may you want to use PowerShell to achive this.

Comment: Are you open to VBA solution?

Comment: Only needed to use Remove Duplicate option in this case. Had to use substitute and remove spaces first however

Answer (score 3):

If you can get the data into Excel this would work (though I know it doesn't 'directly' answer your question, perhaps it will get you started).

```
Sub UniqueColors()

Dim Dictionary As Object
Set Dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each Item In Range("A1:A8")
    If Not Dictionary.exists(Item.Value) And Item.Value <> "" Then
        Dictionary.Add Item.Value, Item.Address
    End If
Next

Range("B1") = Join(Dictionary.keys, ",")
Set Dictionary = Nothing

End Sub
```

You will need to adjust the ranges. Hope that helps!

Comment: Probably a good idea to add `Set Dictionary = Nothing` before `End Sub`, too. I adjusted the code accordingly.